# Validation language on Microsoft Azure Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, web, .net-4.5

I am using mvc 4 on an Microsoft Azure Website (not a VM). Is there any way to change the validation language?

I use a FilterAttribute, to set the language on the action

```
public class LocalizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Globals.Culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Globals.Culture;

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

When my Globals.Culture is "de-DE" on azure, the validation messages are still in english.

[image]

On my local test system it is working, for both german and english.

I also tried to remove the client side validation scripts, so that the validation messages are not generated on client side. But it does not work either.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```